# Turtlebot2 Kobuki usb error

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys I need a little help we have 5 turtlebots in our lab, 2 work fine but we're having trouble with the other 3. They power up fine but do not show up as a device (either /dev/kobuki or /dev/ttyUSB*)

dmesg outputs the following error message:

hub 2-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 4 disabled

We've tried different cables, laptops, fully charging the robots and switching to firmware update mode and get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106891/turtlebot2-kobuki-usb-error/) by [richardw347](https://answers.ros.org/users/4193/richardw347/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-04**:
Did that ever work? If the same procedure/laptop works on some and not others, this might be a hardware problem and might be something for the support.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-12-11**:
Yes, contact us directly on the address jihoonl posted above. We'd like to investigate the problem as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might be a hardware issue. I would recommend to contact kobuki@yujinrobot.com

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2013-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0